# Div inside Div align?

Tags: css, html, centering

This is my code >> http://jsfiddle.net/374Rk/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="buttons"></div>
    <div class="chef"></div>
    <div class="social"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have several divs inside a big div container. Everything is centered, but I want the social div (last one) to stick to the right, with a margin of 20 px so everything is in place. Which one is the best way to do this?

If I give social a relative position, I could do this by simply adding the right property with 590px. Is this the correct way to do it? It's not that elegant! Also, if I float it right, it won't be anymore on the container (because I floated it).

This has been always bugging me while working on CSS. I hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set the floating of your .social-div to right. To let the wrapper still wrap all of its childs a clearfix can help:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="buttons"></div>
    <div class="chef"></div>
    <div class="social"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social {
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color: #FF0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AvLU8/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Way clever and elegant fix! :D Also .container with Overflow:Auto works without adding a new div with clear:both!

Answer (score 0):

Check this
http://jsfiddle.net/374Rk/17/

```
.social{
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #FF0;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:590px;
}
```

Comment: But it's not into the container anymore if I float it! Check the fiddle, with float it's not into the gray container, it leaves it! That's what I want to know, how to align it to the right without leaving the container and without using relative position + right: 590px.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to float it (and correct everything), you could add `text-align: right;` to the `.container` and `display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px;` to `.social`.

http://jsfiddle.net/374Rk/3/

But I don't know what you want inside each div. So, probably you'll need to add `text-align: left;` to each `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Martínez,
I have read out your query and find a solution using JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.container div').each( function() {   
        container = $(this).attr('class');  
        content = $(this);  
        if(content == "social"){  
            $( ".container" ).addClass( "social" );  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Check on below url
http://jsfiddle.net/374Rk/30/